# Configure IIS for smartcard authentication where certificate and subject are provided by proxy server via header injection

Tags: authentication, iis, proxy, smartcard, f5

I have a web server running IIS that authenticates users with smart cards and windows authentication. In the current configuration, IIS prompts the user for their smart card and then authenticates it against Windows.

In a new configuration, this IIS web server will live behind a proxy server. The proxy server will prompt the user for their smart card and then pass along the certificate and subject in the header via header injection.

How do I configure IIS to grab these details from the header and authenticate against Windows as we are doing currently?

Comment: Then you need to write your custom authentication module to extend IIS functionality.

Comment: So you mean that certificate information will store in http headers? Did you try to write code to get headers' value to complete authen? `string HearderValue = Request.Headers["xxxxx"];`